# MIMIC III dataset handling

Tags: database, medical, heartrate

how can i understand  for a particular PLETH signal (3000125_0028) record what is the corresponding heartrate from the numerical record (3000125n).

I want to know for a physiological segment what is the corresponding recorded heartrate (for ex.). I try to check any id is mention to find for that particular segment is mentioned in the numercial record (filename ends with 'n') but i didn't find any key to relate.

https://physionet.org/content/mimic3wdb/1.0/#files-panel